# Unable to execute curl command from php script?

Tags: php, python, python-2.7, curl, post

I tried to create a PHP script which will be invoked when someone click on a button and will be taken to `vt.php` now I want to download the sample based on the VT hash which is received from previous PHP page now I tried using this logic but it is not working.

```
<?php


$fileHash = $_POST['hash'];

echo $fileHash;
#$command = escapeshellcmd("python vt_download.py $fileHash");
$command = escapeshellcmd("curl -v --location https://www.virustotal.com/vtapi/v2/file/download?apikey=APIKEY\&hash=$fileHash -o $fileHash");
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;

?>
```

**Output**
c75b5e2ca63adb462f4bb941e0c9f509

**Expected output**
c75b5e2ca63adb462f4bb941e0c9f509
File Downloding Process ------- curl output

When this page is called it is only printing the hash and not downloading the file.Any suggestions to solve this?

P.S : [Error in downloading file from VirusTotal only on server?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42486514/5908241) -- Previously asked this question here,either this or that using python will help.

Comment: No need to use shell_exec, it's an open door for security leaks, especially in your case where you're providing user inputed data. cUrl exists as a PHP library too  : http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: You're using `escaeshellcmd` but you also seem to have done some manual escaping. It should be one or the other.

Comment: @SirMcPotato ```<?php


#$fileHash = $_POST['hash'];
$fileHash = 'c75b5e2ca63adb462f4bb941e0c9f509';
#echo $5e2ca63adb462f4bb941e0c9f509i9
curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_URL , "https://www.virustotal.com/vtapi/v2/file/download?apikey=APIKEY\&hash=$fileHash -o $fileHash");

curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);


?>
``` Is it Correct?

Comment: @apokryfos any alternative ways of using it??

Comment: @BackdoorCipher It's the idea. Making an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use [PHP cURL library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) instead of using the `shell_exec` function that can quickly lead to security issues when using user-inputed data.

```
<?php
    $fileHash = $_POST['hash'];

    // Initializing cURL, we can put the URL in the curl_init function
    $ch = curl_init("https://www.virustotal.com/vtapi/v2/file/download?apikey=AP‌​IKEY&hash=$fileHash");

    // We need to retrieve the response, setting appropriate options :
    curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER , true);

    // Executing the request
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    // Error verification
    if (!$result){
        echo('Error: "' . curl_error($ch) . '" - Code: ' . curl_errno($ch));
    }
    curl_close($ch);
?>
```